# WebNMS - SNMPv3 over SHA-DES not working

Tags: java, snmp, webnms

When using WebNMS java based SNMP APIs for communication with SNMPv3, I am getting following error on using SHA-DES combination. All other combinations(MD5-DES, noAuthNoPriv etc) are working fine.

> Digest Failed : RemoteHost = 10.121.32.163 : RemotePort = 5000 : UserName = batty
>
> returning : -1could not send a wrongDigests report PDU Failed to authenticate the SecurityParameters for user batty authKey length has to be 20

WebNMS low-level API errors say the following about the error:

> If an SNMPv3 message is send to an SNMPv3 agent, it checks whether the authParams is correct. In case if the authParams is incorrect, it sends this error to the originator. The agent developed using WebNMS SNMP API will automatically send the report PDU on receiving the SNMP message. If the authParams of the message is wrong, this error is sent to the originator.

and

> AuthProtocol: SHA
> Context Name, ContextEngineID are not specified.

But I verified that all this information is correct.

Anybody who encountered this issue? How to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in USMUtils.password_to_key API. It returns auth key with length 16 when priv protocol (AES-128 and DES) are used with auth protocol SHA.

Used deprecated password_to_key to solve the issue.

> Deprecated. This method cannot be used to generate localized privacy key if the privacy protocol is other than CBC_DES and CFB_AES_128.